# RSA decryption in error in php using phpseclib

Tags: php, rsa, cakephp-3.0, phpseclib

Hi I am trying to decrypt the message using phpseclib. The error i am getting is

```
"Class 'phpseclib\Crypt\Base' not found"
```

I am using decrypt code from below url:

http://www.sitepoint.com/encrypt-large-messages-asymmetric-keys-phpseclib/

Comment: You need to include the phpseclib sources. It's better to use the original manual instead of a 3rd party tutorial like sitepoint. Include is explained here: [`http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/`](http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: Thanks @DanFromGermany

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the version you're using is using namespaces. Which means you're using either phpseclib 2.0 or the version in the master branch on github. What you'll need to do, in this case, is to use a PSR-4 compliant autoloader.

Best approach would be just use Composer to install phpseclib as a dependency. eg. do `composer require phpseclib/phpseclib:~2.0` via the CLI in your projects directory and then do this:

```
<?php 
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php' 

use phpseclib\Crypt\RSA; 

$rsa = new RSA();
```

But if you don't want to do that you should also be able to do this:

```
<?php
include('autoload.php'); // https://raw.githubusercontent.com/composer/composer/master/src/Composer/Autoload/ClassLoader.php 

$loader = new \Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader(); 
$loader->addPsr4('phpseclib\\', __DIR__.'/path/to/phpseclib'); 
$loader->register();

use \phpseclib\Crypt\RSA;

$rsa = new RSA();
```